# Making a label in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I don't know how to use SwiftUI and I need to put in a `label = 0` and for every time your iphone `y > 3` its adds `1` to the label.

```
motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.2

motionManager.startGyroUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, Error) in
    if let myData = data
    {
        if myData.rotationRate.y > 3
        {
            tiltOut = tiltOut + 1
            self.tiltOutput.text = "\(tiltOut)"
        }
```

I want to view the `0` on the screen and have it add `1` for every `y > 3`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `@State var labelText: String` for this.

When you update that text the label should update automatically.

```swift
struct MotionView: View {

   @State private var labelText: String = ""

   var body: some View {
       Text(self.labelText)
          .onAppear {
             self.startGyro()
          }
   }

   func startGyro() {

    motionManager.gyroUpdateInterval = 0.2

    motionManager.startGyroUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) { (data, Error) in
    if let myData = data
    {
        if myData.rotationRate.y > 3
        {
            tiltOut = tiltOut + 1
            self.tiltOutput.text = "\(tiltOut)"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

This should work. But I didn't test it.